# Did they boil sacrices of the altar?

Tags: offering

according to Leviticus 6:28

> But the earthen vessel in which it is boiled shall be broken. And if
> it is boiled in a bronze pot, it shall be both scoured and rinsed in
> water.

This was part of the law of the sin offering I thought. In Leviticus 6:24-29. Can someone explain this with scripture references if needed?

Comment: Welcome to the group Christine. I reformatted your question to make it clearer for readers.  BTW please take a look at the Tour and Help pages (below, left) when you have a chance if you have not done so yet.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, yes, they boiled the offering -- although perhaps not exactly at the altar. Part of the animal would be offered up at the altar and the blood would be used to consecrate new priests. Some parts were then burned on the altar and other cuts were boiled inside the sacred area and eaten. A specific instance is detailed in Ex. 30, known as an Installation/Consecration Ram:

> Procure a young bull and two unblemished rams...  take [one] ram, and
> when Aaron and his sons have laid their hands on its head, 20
> slaughter it... {more details here}...
> 31 You shall take (part of) the installation ram and boil its meat in a holy
> place. 32 At the entrance of the tent of meeting Aaron and his sons
> shall eat the meat of the ram and the bread that is in the basket. 33
> They themselves are to eat of these things by which atonement was made
> at their installation and consecration.

Vs. 14 specifies that this is a sin offering (also called a purification offering) by the way, although it is a special case. So yes, there were certain occasions where edible parts of an animal were offered up at the altar and then boiled, rather than being burned.